# jest - resolve promise before tests

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I want to write tests for promise result and I dot'n want to resolve promise in each `it/pit` section.

I need smth like this:

```
describe('getData() results test', () => { 
  return getData().then(response =>  { 
    it('foo', () => expect(response.foo).toEqual(1));

    it('bar', () => expect(response.bar).toEqual(2));

    it('bar', () => expect(response.bar).toEqual(3));
  });
});
```

---

If use `beforeEach` - promise will be resolved as many times as number of `it` sections. I need to resolve it once and then test response. There are a lot of test cases so I want to split all tests into `it` sections

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [How to pass variable from beforeEach hook to tests in jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52397708/1048572), [How to share data between beforeAll / beforeEach and tests in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48528502/1048572)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `beforeAll` function is called only once before all the specs in describe are run.

When return promise, Jest will wait for the promise to resolve before letting the test run.

```
describe('getData() results test', () => { 
  let data = null;

  beforeAll(() => getData().then(response => {
    data = response;
  }));

  it('foo', () => expect(data.foo).toEqual(1));

  it('bar', () => expect(data.bar).toEqual(2));

  it('bar', () => expect(data.bar).toEqual(3));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Async tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html#content) from the Jest documentation. I believe you need something like this:

```
describe('getData() results test', () => { 
    var response;
    beforeEach(() => {
        response = getData();
    });

    it('foo', () => { return response.then(r => expect(r.foo).toEqual(1))});

    it('bar', () => { return response.then(r => expect(r.bar).toEqual(2))});

    it('bar', () => { return response.then(r => expect(r.bar).toEqual(3))});
});
```

Key bit of the docs:

> The promise that is being tested should be returned.

Comment: in your example promise will be resolved 3 times. I need to resolve it once and then tests response. There are a lot of test cases so I want to split all tests into `it` sections

Comment: `The promise that is being tested should be returned.` there was `pit` section for promises. But seems now `it` could be used

Answer (score 1):

> This is not an answer to your question but it may help people comming from Google

Jest will await the promises returned from `beforeAll` or `beforeEach` as @tuchk4 mentioned.

In my case, I forgot the `it` function and implemented the test right into `describe`. Surprisingly enough, this "works" but the promises from `beforeAll` and `beforeEach` will **not** be awaited and this makes all sense

I said "works" on quote because failed `expect()` will indeed fail but the Promise they return will not be awaited which will cause a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.

Answer (score -2):

You can simply do the following

```
describe('some test suite title', () => {
   let response;

   beforeAll(async (done) => {
    // Do some Async. logic before running any test
    await require('./somefile');
    response = await getData();
    done();
  });

    // Now run tests => response have the data
    it('foo', () => expect(response.foo).toEqual(1));

    it('bar', () => expect(response.bar).toEqual(2));

    it('bar', () => expect(response.bar).toEqual(3));
  
});
```

Comment: From testing this logic, it appears that Jest requires a promise or callback, it won't accept both.