# How to pass variable from beforeEach hook to tests in jest?

Tags: jestjs

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  const sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()
  ...
})

test('/add', () => {
  // how can I use sandbox here?
})
```

What I need is something like `t.context` in ava

Comment: I want to do the opposite: **How to pass variable from `test` or `describe` to `beforeEach` hook?**

Comment: @JoshuaPinter You might want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Just declare sandbox so it is available in the scope of beforeEach and test:

```js
let sandbox;

beforeEach(async () => {
  sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()
  ...
})

test('/add', () => {
  // sandbox available for use
})
```

Comment: Won't this be an issue if several tests using `sandbox` run in parallel?

Comment: No, this isn't an issue.  `Jest` may run **test suites** (entire test files) in parallel, but by default `Jest` runs the tests **within** a test suite ["serially in the order they were encountered in the collection phase, waiting for each to finish and be tidied up before moving on."](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown#order-of-execution-of-describe-and-test-blocks) @OoDeLally

Comment: Could you not just use `this.sandbox` instead of `let sandbox`? Works for me, but not sure how Jest and Jasmine interplay and versions of both.

Comment: It would be an issue though if using test.concurrent... Or not?

Comment: I thought about create the sandbox as an queue array, and, in each test push a new element into that array.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not supposed to do it like this... [see here](https://jestjs.io/docs/troubleshooting#defining-tests).  I use static variables on a TestUtils class that I set in the beforeall hook and clear in the afterall hook, it seems to work. IDK if it is conventionally correct though.

Comment: @jhilliar you referenced an article about wrapping a test definition in an asynchronous method. Doing so causes the test to not be found during the test-discovery phase. This is unrelated to the problem at hand, which is a problem of scope, not execution.
edit: The side effect of the question being a bad example because it is asynchronous simply causes a Promise to be created in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment as I don't have enough karma, but with regards to Brian's answer, what's the difference between doing what he showed and just running the code before `test`?

```
describe('test', () => {
  let sandbox;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create()
  })

  test('/add', () => {})
});
```

VS

```
describe('test', () => {
  let sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();

  test('/add', () => {})
});
```

I understand how they would be different if using `beforeEach` (as opposed to `beforeAll`) – but are these approaches somehow different when using `beforeAll`?